# awk merging 2 columns and adding an extra column to txt file

Tags: awk, columnsorting

I did this in the past without problems, but I can't this time and I don't understand why.....

My original files is

```
1002       10214
1002       10220
1002       10222
1002       10248
1002       10256
```

I need to make a new file where the 2 columns above are merged and add a second column with value 1

Desired output should look like this

```
100210214    1
100210220    1
100210222    1
100210248    1
100210256    1
```

I tried the below awk commands to first print the 2 columns into 1 into a tmp file, then adding the extra column with "1"

```
cat input.txt |  awk '{ print ($1$2)}' > tmp1.txt

cat tmp1.txt | awk ' {print $0, (1) }' > output.txt
```

While the first command seems working ok, the second does not

tmp1.txt (OK)

```
100210214    
100210220    
100210222    
100210248    
100210256
```

output.txt (not OK)

```
 10210214
 10210220
 10210222
 10210248
 10210256
```

The "1"comes in the front of the first column, not sure why, even replacing the first 2 characters. Is it because the original input file is different (may be "space" was used instead of tab)?

Comment: `awk '{$1=$1$2;$2=1}1' file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when input file has Windows line endings (i.e. `\r\n`). You can fix it using this command:

```
dos2unix file
```

and then get the desired output with this one:

```
awk '{$1=$1$2;$2=1}1' file
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Windows line endings was definitely the problem

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {sub(/\r$/,"");print $1 $2,"1"}'  Input_file
```

Comment: does not work unless I do first dos2unix file

Comment: Huh? The `gsub` does the same thing as `dos2unix`.

Comment: @tripleee, sorry if I am wrong here, I thought it will remove all `\r` characters from line.

Comment: Well yes, if you can find a file where there are CR characters somewhere else than at the end of the line, this will do something slightly different than `dos2unix`

Comment: @tripleee, sure sir, I have changed command to `sub(/\r$/,"")` now.

Comment: I was reacting to the OP's assertion that this "doesn't work" though.